# How can i include volume data in docker image

Tags: deployment, docker, dockerfile

I had docker image (mybase) created from file with two volumes

```
# set volume mount points for installation and home directory
VOLUME ["/usr/local/data", "/var/local/data"]
```

Now i want to new image for production which will have that data as part of image so that i can just pull it. But i don't know how to access that data .

I want to do something like this . This will be my new `Dockerfile for prod` which will create image from current

```
FROM mybase
ADD /usr/local/data:/usr/local/data
```

But that dir is not on host so i don't know how can i add it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the nature of the data, you might also see it as the part of the image. In such case you can carry these files with the image. You could structure this as a base image and an image for a particular build, which would be built on a host that has access to the files needed (e.g. CI build node):

```
FROM mybase
ADD <source of installation> /usr/local/data
ADD <source of the home data> /var/local/data
```

This new image (possibly versioned per build) would be pulled with the contents of the `/usr/local/data` and `/var/local/data` onto the target environment.

When running on environment (production) you might still use the data container technique if needed:

```
docker run --it -v /usr/local/data -v /var/local/data --name my_app_data_container <my_repo>/<my_app>:<build> /bin/false
docker run -d --volumes-from my_app_data_container --name my_app_daemon <my_repo>/<my_app>:<build>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue and finally decided to backup and restore [the way they describe in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes):

To back up:

```
sudo docker run --volumes-from dbdata-prod \
  -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /dbdata
```

...and restore...

```
sudo docker run --volumes-from dbdata-test \
  -v $(pwd):/backup busybox tar xvf /backup/backup.tar
```

Comment: thanks for that , so it means every when when code change i have to do like this. this  looks very bad method of deploying . i can't understand why i can't add code in docker image.  I really see no point using volumes and data containers . using host volume makes things so easy . i can just add code from host with no issues besides permissions

Comment: If you have code on the host and want to mount it in the containers, you're doing what I used to do up until recently, but it still becomes hard to manage. I've changed this to use data containers and written a small utility that makes it easy to access the code in the data containers. It's called Docker Shell (dsh) and provides shell and file share access to a data container that contains the code you're working on. https://github.com/Notalib/dsh

Comment: My main reason for switching to a pure container approach is that I can now let other developers set up the entire container environment on their own workstation, regardless of their OS (they just use boot2docker) and preferred IDE. dsh is all they need to bootstrap it.